# Python: Get the RA flag from DNS

Tags: python, dns, dnspython

I'm trying to specifically get the Recursion Available (RA) flag from the DNS. According to the RFC 1035, if there's no recursion it should return zero, otherwise non-zero. If a DNS response is blocked by Quad9 DNS service it returns an "NXDOMAIN" with a "RA:0"

However, using DNSPython is always returns non-zero (128). Can this hardcoded in the [library](https://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/)?

```
import dns
import dns.resolver

# Allowed Domain
# should return an IP address with "RA" non-zero
domain = "google.com"

# Blocked domain 
# Should return NXDOMAIN with "RA" to 0
#domain = "takelady.net" ---> UNCOMMENT

# Set Resolver to Quad9 (quad9.net)
my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
my_resolver.nameservers = ['9.9.9.9']

try:
    dns_response = dns.resolver.query(domain, "A")

    for resp in dns_response:
        print("[+]", resp.to_text())

    print("RA flag:", dns.flags.RA)
    
except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
    print("[+] NXDOMAIN")
    print("RA flag:", dns.flags.RA)
    pass

except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
    print("[+] NoAnswer")
    pass

except dns.resolver.Timeout:
    print("[+] Timeout")
    pass
```

Allowed Response:

```
[+] 172.217.214.100
[+] 172.217.214.101
[+] 172.217.214.138
[+] 172.217.214.139
[+] 172.217.214.113
[+] 172.217.214.102
RA flag: 128
```

Blocked Response:

```
[+] NXDOMAIN
RA flag: 128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the resolver object you have created, so queries go to the system resolver.  You should use this instead:

```
dns_response = my_resolver.query(domain, "A")
```

`query()` performs search list processing, so you should clear the search list first, like this:

```
    my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    my_resolver.nameservers = ['9.9.9.9']
    my_resolver.search = []
```

Finally, the `NXDOMAIN` response results in an exception, and you need to read the flags from the response object in the exception, like this:

```
except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN as e:
    print("[+] NXDOMAIN")
    for (name, resp) in e.responses().items():
        print(name, "RA flag:", resp.flags & dns.flags.RA)
```

Comment: I am having the "NameError: name 'e' is not defined" error within the "e.responses().items()" -> any import is missing?

Comment: Did you include the `as e` on the `except` line?

Comment: Well-spotted! but still having an error, code here: https://pastebin.com/WPFCdxK5

Comment: AttributeError: 'NXDOMAIN' object has no attribute 'responses'

Comment: What are your Python and dnspython version? Your code works for me with Python 3.7.3 and dnspython 1.16.0.

Comment: Tested with 3.6.3 (1.15.0) - will try to upgrade to 1.16

Comment: I did upgrade to dnspython 1.16.0 and worked fine! Thanks for taking the time to help me.